# How does the sun work in Tiny Wings?

Tags: tiny-wings

In *Tiny Wings* (iOS), I would like to get to island 8, and I'm wondering: does the sun just tick down at a constant time, chasing you as you fly (therefore, you want to fly as fast as possible)? Or does it speed up as you get to later islands?

Also, does it have a maximum where you can't get too far ahead of it? (I.e., if you go super fast on the first island, does it actually help more than going regular fast? Or can you only get so far in front of the sun?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATED:** I wasn't really satisfied that my previous answer was correct, so I spent some time experimenting. I was partly right and partly wrong.

Experiment 1:

- I traversed the 1st island with the screen pressed nonstop. It took approximately 60 seconds for the day/night division line to move from 90° (vertical) to approximately 20°.
- I traversed the 2nd island with the screen pressed nonstop. It took approximately 35-40 seconds for the day/night division line to move from 90° (vertical) to approximately 20°.
- I traversed the 3rd island with the screen pressed nonstop. It took approximately 30 seconds for the day/night division line to move from 90° (vertical) to approximately 20°.
- **Conclusion: The sun goes down progressively faster on each island.**

Experiment 2:

- I performed Experiment 1 with a nest multiplier of x0 and x23. Results were extremely similar.
- **Conclusion: Nest level does not appear to affect the speed of the sun.**

Experiment 3:

- I went off the island 1 to island 2 jump at minimum speed. The sun went backward approximately 70°.
- I went off the island 2 to island 3 jump at minimum speed. The sun went backward approximately 35°.
- **Conclusion: End of island jumps push back the sun, regardless of speed. These boosts diminish on each consecutive island (and appear to be gone completely by the 3rd or 4th jump.)**

Experiment 4:

- I traversed nearly all of island 1 in fever mode. The sun moved backward approximately 10-20°.
- Tried slides, cloud touches and coin collecting. None of these activities, individually, appeared to have any effect on the sun.
- I deleted and reinstalled the game for Experiment 2, and I noticed that I was able to get to mid-island 7 pretty consistently, regardless of my much lower nest multiplier (and total score). So it appears that speed, not points, cause the sun to roll back or slow down.
- **Conclusion: Going fast can push back the sun. Slides and cloud touches don't seem to have a major effect on the sun, although these are tied up with speed. This speed effect may also diminish on later islands, or it may simply be countered by the sun setting faster.**
- **Bonus Conclusion: There is a limit to how far the sun can be rolled back, about 90° backward from the starting position (with the sun just beyond the left edge of the screen).**

Comment: see @Mike Hawk's answer below.  I'm pretty sure he's right... My sun does not get turned back as much between islands.

Comment: @Michael - I agree, at least partly. I've expanded and corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the more nests you have the faster the sun goes down. I used to be able to reach island 7, but now I can't get halfway through island six without it dying. I looked at the sun in the corner and it was moving in a weird way. It started to set at island 1, and then when I jumped over to island 2 it just sped up super fast.

Comment: I agree with you. The sun definitely does not get rolled back as much at least between island 5 and 6 and 7 as it does after 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: I disagree that nest level affects the speed of the sun (see experiment 2 in my answer). The layout of the islands changes each day - perhaps recent layouts have just been tougher for you?

Answer (score 0):

I had a hunch at one point that the sun does not move while you're in fever mode.
This is not true.

**The sun moves as per normal while in fever mode.**

Proof: the day ending while I was in fever mode. Man was I peeved.

Comment: From my experiments, I believe this depends on where you are. Fevering across island 1 quite clearly does push the sun back (even before you hit the jump). On later islands, going that fast is only enough to stop the sun, and eventually the sun is going so fast that it still moves forward, even when you're in fever mode.